# Does inclusion of {} matter in C string initialization?

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following?

```
char input[] = {"abc"};
```

and

```
char input[] = "abc";
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both forms are equivalent and permitted.

```
char input[] = "abc";
```

or

```
char input[] = {"abc"};
```

Here is the relevant paragraph from the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.7.8p14): "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces"